# Planet not able to get a response from quick-search API call

Tags: python, api, planet

My question is related to:
[Planet API not being accepted for quick search but is on stats](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316030/planet-api-not-being-accepted-for-quick-search-but-is-on-stats) and [planet quick-search api not recognizing authentication?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239503/planet-quick-search-api-not-recognizing-authentication).

I am not able to successfully get a response from Planet 14 days trial API call for quick-search, I get the following error:

> {'message': 'Please enter your API key, or email and password.', 'errors': []}

Edit1: my code is as follows:

```
 #AREA of Interest
geojson_geometry = {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [ 
      [-19.423828125,-4.653079918274038],
      [51.591796875,-4.653079918274038],
      [51.591796875,45.336701909968134],
      [-19.423828125,45.336701909968134],
      [-19.423828125,-4.653079918274038]
    ]
  ]
}
#Images overlapping out area of interest
> geometry_filter = {
>     "type": "GeometryFilter",
>     "field_name": "geometry",
>     "config": geojson_geometry }

#for a specific date range

> date_range_filter = {
>     "type": "DateRangeFilter",
>     "field_name": "acquired",
>     "config": {
>         "gte": "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
>         "lte": "2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
>     } }

#images with less than 50% cloud range

> cloud_cover_filter = {
>     "type": "RangeFilter",
>     "field_name": "cloud_cover",
>     "config": {
>         "lte": 0.5
>     } }

#combine geometry, date and cloud filters

> combined_filter = {
>     "type": "AndFilter",
>     "config": [geometry_filter, date_range_filter, cloud_cover_filter] }
> 
> import os import json import requests from requests.auth import
> HTTPBasicAuth

#PLANET_API_KEY = os.getenv('c43b6ae27338421dad81dd7c2a5306a6')

> os.environ["PLANET_API_KEY"] = "c43b6ae27338421dad81dd7c2a5306a6"
> 
> item_type = "PSScene4Band"

#API request object

> search_request = {
>     "interval": "day",
>     "item_types": [item_type],
>     "filter": combined_filter } search_result = requests.post('https://api.planet.com/data/v1/quick-search',
> auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''), json= search_request)
> 
> print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. Can you provide the code you are running to make the call?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your API Key is empty or null (my first guess) or invalid. You should follow these steps:

1. Store your environmental variables outside your code. You can use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228345/how-to-reference-a-file-for-variables-using-bash). Basically, create

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PLANET_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'
```

Then before running your python script, execute the file.

2. If the API Key you are sharing here is your real one, please edit your question and remove it. I would suggest also to regenerate.
3. Replace this line...

```py
os.environ["PLANET_API_KEY"] = "YOUR_API_KEY"
```

...with this other:

```
PLANET_API_KEY = os.environ["PLANET_API_KEY"]
```

4. Run your python script.